# Turning RPi Official Display(Touchscreen)'s backlight on/off from python on pi user account

Tags: python, display, touchscreen

I'm not sure if this issue belongs here or on the python side, but hopefully someone can help me on this, and others can benefit here as well.

---

I've managed to customize the commands found in [this discussion](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=120296), combining knowledge from [this question about echoing sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-privilegedfile-doesnt-work-is-there-an-alterna), and managed to get

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power > /dev/null
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power > /dev/null
```

as a working command-line entry to turn the backlight on and off from the pi user account.

```
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power"
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power"
```

worked equally well.

---

Now, combining a `subprocess.Popen()` method in python (referring to [this page](http://www.ridgesolutions.ie/index.php/2013/02/22/raspberry-pi-restart-shutdown-your-pi-from-python-code/)), I've tried

```
@staticmethod
def screen_off():
    command  = "echo 1 | /usr/bin/sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power"
    process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.communicate()[0]
    print(output)
```

and

```
@staticmethod
def screen_off():
    commandarr = ["/usr/bin/sudo","/bin/sh","-c","\"echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power\""]
    process = subprocess.Popen(commandarr, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.communicate()[0]
    print(output)
```

to no avail; the former prints

```
b'1 | /usr/bin/sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power\n'
```

and the latter

```
/bin/sh: 1: echo 1 > /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power: not found
b''
```

the latter using the split() method gives

```
1: 1: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
b''
```

The shutdown counterpart works OK, so it probably isn't a user privilege issue...
The former is probably a problem using the pipe method, and the latter a problem with quotes and/or the sh -c parameter not going through...

Is there any way around these problems, or would I be better off writing a shell script and calling that instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've managed to find a solution for the former method.
 The problem was with trying to use pipes within one process call, so I referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389662/link-several-popen-commands-with-pipes) and used two process calls and piped them together:

```
@staticmethod
def screen_off():
    command1 = "echo 1"
    command2 = "/usr/bin/sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power"
    process1 = subprocess.Popen(command1.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process2 = subprocess.Popen(command2.split(), stdin=process1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process2.communicate()[0]
    print(output)
```

to get the screen to turn off properly...!